# How to make (copy - cut - share) Text Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3mOF.jpg)

When long tab on Text widget, a tooltip show up with 'copy' and 'share'.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for SelectableText widget
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectableText` widget for this.

```
child: SelectableText(
      'Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum',
      cursorColor: Colors.blue,
      showCursor: true,
      toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
          copy: true, selectAll: true, cut: true, paste: true),
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2,
    ),
```

Check the documentation for more options: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html